# how to convert mysql query to sequelize syntax?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME 
FROM products_1 
ORDER BY if(CUSTOMER_NAME = '' or CUSTOMER_NAME is null,1,0),
         CUSTOMER_NAME
```

I am using node.js for backend development and started using Sequelize library but stuck with above syntax conversion to MySQL client query to Sequelize syntax.

Output I am trying to get was `CUSTOMER_NAME` in alphabetical order and `null`, empty spaces in last. If there is any alternative way in Sequelize want to know.

Comment: Use `SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME FROM products_1 ORDER BY CUSTOMER_NAME > '',         CUSTOMER_NAME`. Anycase this needs in raw SQL. Or you' в use a subquery which is excess in this task I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to build using literals. literals will allow you to combine your queries with raw ones.

```
Schema.findAll({
        attributes : ["CUSTOMER_NAME"],
        order : [sequelize.literal(`if(CUSTOMER_NAME = '' or CUSTOMER_NAME is null,1,0), CUSTOMER_NAME`)],
    })
```